# Why use spread operator to merge two arraies then report an Unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, ecmascript-6, frontend

this is my code:

```js
let arrA = [1,2,3]
let arrB = [3,4,5,6]
let result = []
//  error: Unexpected token
[...arrA,...arrB].forEach(item => {
  if(arrA.includes(item)&&!arrB.includes(item)) result.push(item)
})
console.log(result)
```

but this work well

```js
Array.from([...arrA,...arrB]).forEach(item => {
  if(arrA.includes(item)&&!arrB.includes(item)) result.push(item)
})
```

how does it comes?

Comment: Missing a semicolon at the end of `let result = []`

Comment: but semicolon is optional.

Comment: ASI will not trigger here, so no, it isn't.

Comment: No. `[][...stuff]` is a malformed property access with bracket notation

Comment: See [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) , trying to find a dupe for this, but it's hard, as they always use "cannot access property ... of ..." as title, which is also used by 349825734 others.

Comment: http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons

Comment: @ASDFGerte feel free to ping me if you find a better one :)

Comment: thanks all. I got it.

Comment: @HussainNawazLalee no, not at all, it will just say `[] is not a function`, due to the exact same reasons.